# do you have to specify the length of the type in a sproc parameter?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters

Does SQL Server allow you to declare stored procedure parameters like this?

```
@username NVARCHAR
```

Or do you always have to specify a size like this?

```
@username NVARCHAR(100)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't specify a length it will default to 1.  Even if that is your intention it is better to be explicit like this:

```
nvarchar(1)
```

**Edit:** I should have pointed out that my previous statement only applies to declarations - if you are using `nvarchar` in a `cast` statement and omit a length it will default to 30.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to specify a length, at least in SQL Server 2005, but it is a good practice to do so.